# Show a parallelogram with angle $60^\circ$ is a rhombus

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> If $ABCD$ is a parallelogram with $\angle BAD=60 ^\circ$ and $\dfrac{AC^2}{BD^2}=\dfrac31$, show $ABCD$ is a rhombus.

[image]

We have the squares of $AC$ and $BD$ so MAYBE it is a good idea to construct right triangles. Let $DD_1\perp AB$ and $CC_1 \perp AB$. Now we have the right triangles $BD_1D$ and $AC_1C$ with hypotenuses $BD$ and $AC$, respectively. By the Pythagorean theorem we can get $AC^2=AC_1^2+CC_1^2$ and $BD^2=BD_1^2+DD_1^2$. This does not seem to help. Can you give me some hints? Thank you in advane! :)

I am trying to solve it by the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Diagonals of rhombus are perpendicular. Use that.

Comment: You don' t have to show that. That is sth you need to know before taking a task like this and use it as a tool in future, e.g., to understand the answer provided already.

Comment: I meant how to show they are perpendicular and then conclude the parallelogram is rhombus. Not necessary to be rude but it's a common thing here I think.

Comment: What have I said? I just told you this is a starting point.

Comment: I saw you deleted your first question (in the comments) how to prove diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular. There's no need for deleting comments in between a conversation and destructive insinuations about the community.

Comment: I have not deleted the comment you're talking about. I have no reason to do so. It's clear what I meant. And even if I did, what'll happen?

Answer (score 2):

Let $AD_1=x$ and $D_1B=a$

We are given that $AC^2=3BD^2$. Also note that $BC_1=AD_1=x$ because triangles $ADD_1$ and $BCC_1$ are congruent. By the Pythagorean theorem,

$$(2x+a)^2+(\sqrt{3}x)^2=3((\sqrt{3}x)^2+a^2)$$
$$2x^2+2a^2-4ax=0$$
$$(x-a)^2=0$$

so $x=a$. Now you have sufficient information to prove that ABD is an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 2):

If trig permissible, let $ a \neq b$ at start. Using CosineRule, minor diagonal
$$ a^2+b^2- 2ab\cdot  \frac12 = 1$$

and major diagonal

$$ a^2+b^2+2ab\cdot  \frac12 = 3 $$

Add and subtract,

$$ a^2+ b^2= 2,\quad 2ab =2; $$
Solve

$$ a=b=1 $$

So the parallologram has become its special case rhombus.

Comment: Coolest solution so far (+1)!

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if trig is allowed..there is no tag so far, shall put it now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be right on target.

Let $AD=1$ be our unit length.

We want to prove $AB = 1$.

But that would make $\triangle ADD_1$ an isosceles triangle with a $60$ degree vertex, or in other words and equilateral triangle, so $AB=BD=1$.

Let $BD = x$.

We have:

$AD_1 = \frac 12$.  $DD_1= \frac{\sqrt 3}2$. (Because $\triangle ADD_1$ is a $30-60-90$ triangle.)

$D_1B = \sqrt{x^2-\frac 34}$. (By Pythagorean theorem)

$BC_1 = AD_1 =\frac 12$. (Because $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.)

And $AC_1 =AD_1 + D_1B+BC_1 = \sqrt{3x^2 -\frac 34}$.(By Pythagorean theorem)

So we have $\frac 12 + \sqrt{x^2-\frac 34} + \frac 12=\sqrt{x^2-\frac34}+1 = \sqrt{3x^2 -\frac 34}$

Which has solution $x = 1$

And so $D_1B= \sqrt{x^2-\frac 34}=\sqrt{1^2 -\frac 34}=\frac 12$ and $AB = AD_1 + D_1B =1$.

Comment: It is true that $△ADD_1$ is a 30−60−90 triangle, but at the present moment it is not sure that $AD_1=\frac{1}{2}$ or  $DD_1= \frac{\sqrt 3}2.$

Comment: But fleblood assumed that AD is 1 which makes it true

Comment: If $\triangle ADD_1$ is 30-60-90 then $AD_1 = \frac 12 AD$ and $DD_1 = \frac {\sqrt 3}2 AD$.  And we may set $AD$ to our standard unit of $1$.... If you don't like that let $AD=s$ and then we need to prove $AB=s$ and we have $AD_1 = \frac 12s$.  $DD_1= \frac{\sqrt 3}2$s. $D_1B = \sqrt{x^2-\frac 34s^2}$. $BC_1 = \frac 12s$. And $AC_1 =\sqrt{3x^2 -\frac 34s^2}$

If we solve that we get $x = s$ and therefore $AB = s$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta = \angle ADB$ and $\beta = \angle ABD$. It is enough to show that one of them is equal to $60°$.

For convenience, let $a=AD, b=AB, e = AC$, and $f=BD$.So, the parallelogram identity and law of sines give

$$2(a^2+b^2)=e^2+f^2 \stackrel{\frac{e^2}{f^2}= 3}{\Rightarrow} 2\left(\frac{\sin^2\delta}{\sin^2 60°} + \frac{\sin^2\beta}{\sin^2 60°}\right) = 4$$

Hence, after rearranging and noting that $\beta = 180°-60°-\delta$ you get
$$\sin^2\delta + \sin^2(120°-\delta) = \frac 32$$

Using the double-angle formula and reducing angles results in
$$\cos 2\delta + \cos (60°-2\delta) =0$$

and, applying $\cos u + \cos v = 2\cos \frac{u+v}{2}\cos\frac{u-v}{2}$, we obtain

$$\cos (2\delta - 30°) = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{\delta = 60°}$$